How to visualize data models in dataGridView?
How to visualize in the dataGridView control the names of the cities?
Grid

public void UpdateGrid()
{
  List<Counterparty> counterparties = counterpartyController.GetAllCounterparties();
  dGVCounterparties.DataSource = counterparties;
  dGVCounterparties.ReadOnly = true;
  dGVCounterparties.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}

I tried to fix it, but I can`t.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have to tell the dataGrindView the properties for the columns. Something like:
dGVCounterparties.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "CityName";

You can try the AutoGenerateColumns flag.
dGVCounterparties.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

